# pgfplots: How to add a calculation in /.code=...?

Tags: pgfplots

What is the correct syntax to add a calculation in `/.style` or `/.code`?

This does not work:

```
scatter/@pre marker code/.code={
\pgfmathsetmacro\myheight{1.2*\zzz+0.2}
/pgfplots/cube/size z=\myheight
},  % works not
```

What do I have to do?

[image]

```
\documentclass[border=10pt, varwidth]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplotstable}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.17}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}
\usepackage{pgfplots}

\begin{document}
\pgfplotstableread[col sep=comma,header=true]{
X,   Y,    Z
0,    0,   10
1,    0,   5
4,    1,   0
4,    2,   0
}{\datatable}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[]
\addplot3[scatter, mark=*, only marks,
mark=cube*, mark size=5,  
nodes near coords*=\coordindex,
visualization depends on={value \thisrow{Z} \as \zzz},
% Works
scatter/@pre marker code/.append style={
/pgfplots/cube/size z=15   
}, % works
% Works not
%scatter/@pre marker code/.code={
%\pgfmathsetmacro\myheight{1.2*\zzz+0.2}
%/pgfplots/cube/size z=\myheight
%},  % works not
] table [x=X, y=Y] {\datatable};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the key handler `/utils/exec=<code>`, which is described in section 82.4.8 *Handlers for Key Inspection* of the [TikZ-manual](http://mirrors.ctan.org/graphics/pgf/base/doc/pgfmanual.pdf) (not in the pgfplots-manual).

So

```
visualization depends on={\thisrow{Z} \as \zzz}, 
scatter/@pre marker code/.append style={
/utils/exec=\pgfmathsetmacro\myheight{2.2*\zzz+0.2},
/pgfplots/cube/size z=\myheight        
}, % works as well
```

can be used.

```
\documentclass[border=10pt, varwidth]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplotstable}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.17}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}
\usepackage{pgfplots}

\begin{document}
\pgfplotstableread[col sep=comma,header=true]{
X,   Y,    Z
0,    0,   10
1,    0,   5
4,    1,   0
4,    2,   0
}{\datatable}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[]
\addplot3[scatter, mark=*, only marks,
mark=cube*, mark size=5,  
nodes near coords*=\coordindex,
visualization depends on={\thisrow{Z} \as \zzz}, 
% Works
%scatter/@pre marker code/.append style={
%/pgfplots/cube/size z=15   
%}, % works
% Works as well
scatter/@pre marker code/.append style={
/utils/exec=\pgfmathsetmacro\myheight{2.2*\zzz+0.2},
/pgfplots/cube/size z=\myheight        
}, % works as well
] table [x=X, y=Y] {\datatable};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

I don't know why it failed neither. But after some try, I found the following code works. I think there may exist some expansion problem if we directly use the pgf's math calculation functionality. So I use xfp package for calculation.

```
\documentclass[border=10pt, varwidth]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplotstable}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.17}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}
\usepackage{pgfplots,xfp}

\begin{document}
\pgfplotstableread[col sep=comma,header=true]{
X,   Y,    Z
0,    0,   10
1,    0,   5
4,    1,   0
4,    2,   0
}{\datatable}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}
\addplot3[scatter, mark=*, only marks,
mark=cube*, mark size=5,
nodes near coords*=\coordindex,
visualization depends on={z \as \zzz},
% % Works
scatter/@pre marker code/.append style={
/pgfplots/cube/size z=\fpeval{12*\zzz+0.2}
},
] table [x=X, y=Y] {\datatable};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```